# Enclosing a div element inside another div element destroys the parallax Effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the original working example from w3schools

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.parallax {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url('img_parallax.jpg');

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">
Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.
This div is just here to enable scrolling.
Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>

<div class="parallax"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

if I enclose the parallax div inside another the effect is completely destroyed. Here is the code.

```
<div class>
<div class="parallax"></div>
</div>
```

You can this experiment here : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_parallax_percent

As we can see the parallax effect is comepletely destroyed. But this only happens when you set the height of parallax class in percent. If you change the height property of parallax class to pixels the parallax effect would start working again even with extra div container

```
    height: 1000px;
```

Why is this happening ?
Is there any way using percentage to get parallax effect even when inside another div element as shown ?

Comment: I see it working both in percentage and in pixels, using FF 60 here

Comment: I viewed it in FF 59.0.2 and its not coming. Did you try it in the w3 school's editor ? Even there it has the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is straight forward.

Why it's working with `px` values and not percentage `values` ?

It's because when setting a percentage value, the browser will calculate the element's height based on it's parent's height, So you wrapped the div inside a `heightless` one, therefore `height:100%` will have no effect the div is there but it has no height, so it doesn't show up.

It works at first because it's parent is the body which has `height:100%` means taking it's parent's height which is the html which also has `height:100%` which takes it's height from the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. You are setting the height of `<div class="parallax"></div>` to the height of your parent `<div></div>` who has no height. So, there is no height of the child.

And that's why it is working when you set it in pixels. Got it?

Enter more details IF you want any help!

As long as your **"WHY"** is concerned, here's the answer.